# Poisson in sales

Tags: python, scipy

I see that Poisson is often used to estimate the number of sales in a certain time period (month, for example).

```
from scipy import stats

monthly_average_sales = 30
current_month_sales = 35

mu = monthly_average_sales
x = current_month_sales

up_to_35 = scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu)
above_35 = 1 - up_to_35
```

Suppose I want to estimate the probability that a specific order will close this month. Is this possible? For example, today is the 15th. If a customer initially called me on the 1st of the month, what is the probability that they will place the order before the month is over? They might place the order tomorrow (the 16th) or on the last day of the month. I don't care when, as long as it's by the end of this month.

```
from scipy import stats

monthly_average_sales = 30
current_sale_days_open = 15
number_of_days_this_month = 31
equivalent_number_of_sales = number_of_days_this_month / current_sale_days_open

mu = monthly_average_sales
x = equivalent_number_of_sales

up_to_days_open = scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu)
above_days_open = 1 - up_to_days_open
```

I don't want to abuse statistics to the point that they become meaningless (I'm not a politician!). Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: When it come to a specific instance, It's more like you would want to look for a duration model. Which model to use depends on your assumption. For example, if memory-less property is okay, then  you can use exponential distribution, which is assumes the same kind of data generating process as Poisson.

Comment: I see. If I'm reading correctly at [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-poisson-process-everything-you-need-to-know-322aa0ab9e9a) and [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html), it appears that the cdf function provides this information given as an exponential function.

`from scipy import stats`

`monthly_average_sales = 30`
`current_sale_days_open = 15`
`number_of_days_this_month = 31`
`lambda = monthly_average_sales / number_of_days_this_month` 

`win_probability = 1 - stats.poisson.cdf(current_sale_days_open, poisson_lambda)`